# Получение треков из плейлиста с SoundCloud с помощью JSON на Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, json

Работаю над приложением на Android, которое работает с сервисом SoundCloud. Общий замысел такой: на первом активити отображаются плейлисты, по нажатию на определенный - открывается второе активити и должен появляется список треков данного плейлиста с воспроизведением. С получением списка плейлистов и с воспроизведением уже разобрался, а вот с получением треков данного массива, нет.

```
// так получаю плейлисты
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            ArrayList<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>(); // массив плейлистов
            ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>(); // массив для треков

            if(response.length() > 0){ // если ответ с сервера не пустой, то
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length() ; i++) { // для каждого элемента в полученном массиве ...
                    try {
                        JSONObject playlistObject = response.getJSONObject(i); // извлекаем JSON-объект из полученного массива
                        long id = playlistObject.getLong("id"); // id альбома
                        String title = playlistObject.getString("title"); // название альбома
                        String artworkUrl_PL = playlistObject.getString("artwork_url"); // ссылка на обложку
                        JSONObject user = playlistObject.getJSONObject("user"); // исполнитель (ползователь в SC)
                        String artist = user.getString("username");
                        String genre = playlistObject.getString("genre"); // жанр

                        JSONObject tracks = playlistObject.getJSONObject("tracks");

                        Playlist playlist = new Playlist(id, title, artist, artworkUrl_PL, genre);
                        playlists.add(playlist);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.getMessage());
                        callback.onError_PL("Произошла ошибка");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                callback.onSucsess_PL(playlists, songs);

            }else{
                callback.onError_PL("Не найдено плейлистов");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            callback.onError_PL("Ошибка ответа с сервера");
        }
    });

    queue.add(request);

}
```

> В месте JSONObject tracks = playlistObject.getJSONObject("tracks"); выдает ошибку org.json.JSONException: No value for tracks

[image: то, что нужно получить]

В примере для плейлистов на сайте SoundCloud отображается массив "tracks". Я так понимаю, именно его и нужно получить. Но как? Подскажите пожалуйста.
[Ссылка на документацию SoundCloud](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists)

Кто работал с SoundCloud, поделитесь пожалуйста опытом.

Answer (score 1):

> В примере для плейлистов на сайте SoundCloud отображается массив
>   "tracks".

Ключевое слово здесь "массив". А вы вы пытаетесь получить объект. Массив нужно получать так:

```
JSONArray tracks = playlistObject.getJSONArray("tracks");
```

Если в конкретном Json ответе отсутствует данное поле, то будет вываливаться `org.json.JSONException: No value for tracks`. Чтобы этого избежать, можно сначала проверить, есть ли такое поле в ответе:

```
if (playlistObject.has("tracks")) {
    JSONArray tracks = playlistObject.getJSONArray("tracks");
}
```

Второй вариант, использовать метод `opt...()`:

```
JSONArray tracks = playlistObject.optJSONArray("tracks");
```

Этот метод вернёт объект, если он существует или `null`, если объект не найден (вместо `Exception`).

Comment: Это тоже пробовал, та же ошибка: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tracks

Comment: Значит, что в этом конкретном ответе отсутствует поле `tracks`. Дополнил ответ, как избежать exception.